# Ionic React error in "as" in react-hook-form Controller

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hook-form

I am new to Ionic. I have created a simple form which has a Title and Message field by react-hook-form Controller. So that an error occured in "as"

[Find the Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FusSd.png)

[Error Message in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG0cx.png)

```
import * as  React from "react";
import { IonCard, IonCardContent, IonCardHeader, IonContent, IonHeader, IonTextarea, IonInput, IonLabel, IonPage, IonItem, IonTitle, IonToolbar, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';
import ExploreContainer from '../components/ExploreContainer';
import './Home.css';
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  
  const initialValues = {
    title: "",
    body: ""
  }

  const { control, reset, handleSubmit, formState} = useForm({
    defaultValues: initialValues
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }

  const resetForm = () => {
    reset(initialValues);
  }

  // const renderErrorMessage = (_key : string ) => {
  //   let theErrors = (errors as any)[_key];
  //   return <span>theErrors.message || "This Is A Required Field"</span>
  // } 
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle size="large">Form Test - React Hook Form</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonCard>
          <IonCardHeader>Test Input Form</IonCardHeader>
        </IonCard>

        <IonCardContent>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel>Title</IonLabel>
              <Controller
                as = {IonInput}
                control={control}
                onChangeName="onIonChange"
                onChange={(selected:any) => {
                  return selected.detail.value;
                }}
                name="title"
                rules={{
                  required: true,
                  minLength: { value: 4, message: "Must be 4 chars long" }
                }}
              />
              
            </IonItem>
                {/* {errors.title ? renderErrorMessage("title") : null} */}
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel>Body</IonLabel>
              <Controller
                as = {<IonTextarea rows={5}></IonTextarea>}
                control={control}
                onChangeName="onIonChange"
                onChange={(selected:any) => {
                  return selected.detail.value;
                }}
                name="body"
                rules={{
                  required: true,
                  minLength: { value: 10, message: "Must be 10 chars long" }
                }}
              />
              
            </IonItem>
            {/* {errors.body ? renderErrorMessage("body") : null} */}
            <IonButton type="submit">SAVE</IonButton>
            <IonButton onClick={() => resetForm()}>Reset Form</IonButton>
          </form>
        </IonCardContent>

      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Visual Studio Code display the error line below the as keyword in Controller Tag while defining the input field. I have installed react-hook-form library

Ionic:

Ionic CLI       : 6.18.1
Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 6.0.1

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI      : 3.3.3
@capacitor/android : not installed
@capacitor/core    : 3.3.3
@capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed globally
native-run  : 1.5.0

System:

NodeJS : v16.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 8.1.2
OS     : Windows 10

Comment: Which version of react-hook-form are you using?

Comment: version of react-hook-form is 7.22.2

Comment: you don't need to wrap all those ionic components with a Controller some will work fine with just using the register - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-hook-form-me1pv4?file=src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `as` props have been removed in react-hook-form v7, that's you get this error. (Supposing you're using the v7).
You've to use the `render` prop.

Controller doc: https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller